# ASP.eventtracker_aspx' does not contain a definition

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am going through a ASP C# book and doing the tutorials. However I have encountered a problem. I have the following code that will list some events.

EventTracker.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EventTracker.aspx.cs" Inherits="EventTracker" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <title>Event Tracker</title>
  <style type="text/css">
      h1 
      {
          font-size: large;       
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="Form1" runat="server">
    <div>       
      <h1>Controls being monitored for change events:</h1>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
       OnTextChanged="CtrlChanged" />
      <br /><br />
      <asp:CheckBox ID="chk" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true"
       OnCheckedChanged="CtrlChanged"/>
      <br /><br />
      <asp:RadioButton ID="opt1" runat="server" GroupName="Sample"
       AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CtrlChanged"/>
      <asp:RadioButton ID="opt2" runat="server" GroupName="Sample"
       AutoPostBack="true" OnCheckedChanged="CtrlChanged"/>
      <br /><br /><br /> 
       <h1>List of events:</h1>
      <asp:ListBox ID="lstEvents" runat="server" Width="355px"
       Height="305px" /><br />      
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

EventTracker.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class EventTracker : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Log("<< Page_Load>>");

    }

    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Find the control ID of the sender. 
        //This requires converting the Object type into a control class. 
        string ctrlName = ((Control)sender).ID;
        Log(ctrlName + " Changed");
    }

    protected void Log(string entry)
    {
        lstEvents.Items.Add(entry);

        //Select the last item to scroll the list so the most recent are visible
        lstEvents.SelectedIndex = lstEvents.Items.Count - 1;
    }
}
```

I am recieving the following error:

> Error 1   'ASP.eventtracker_aspx' does not contain a definition for
>   'CtrlChanged' and no extension method 'CtrlChanged' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'ASP.eventtracker_aspx' could be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I am new to ASP and would like to understand why such an error is occurring so in future reference I know what is causing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your markup you have

```
OnCheckedChanged="CtrlChanged"
```

But there is no event handler with that name / matching signature in your codebehind...

This event will be triggered everytime your CheckBox changes, but you do not have anything in the code that will respond.

You need something like

```
protected void CtrlChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)   
    {  // do something }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the event handler for `CtrlChanged()`.

```
protected void CtrlChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      //....handle event
}
```